# Does this diagram follows Microservices, DDD with Event sourcing

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices, event-sourcing

1. Does event sourcing should be at the end of process and should there be event handlers?
2. while following event sourcing I know at any time we can derive application state from events but should we save that state in database as well?
   [image: Architecture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Events are emitted after domain logic was executed (some operation was performed on the entity/domain object). Firstly event is persisted in the store and then published to the bus and other consumers (microservices, event handlers from your diagramm) can subscribe on it. Persist and publish of the event should be like a transaction.
2. Every time when new operation needs to be executed on domain object the whole set of events is reading from the Event Store for that entity. Some entities can have a lot of events and to optimize performance so called **State Snapshots** are used. Basically it is State of the domain object after X events. Snapshots can be created every X events. They stored separately in the Event Store and usually Event Sourcing libraries allow to configure Snapshots. But it's just for performance purposes.

I've quickly created diagram to show that is usually happened inside *Command Handler*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to use the CQRS + Event sourcing pattern.

Here are some examples:

- https://dzone.com/articles/microservices-with-cqrs-and-event-sourcing
- https://danielwhittaker.me/2020/02/20/cqrs-step-step-guide-flow-typical-application/

According to the links above, you can fix your architecture and I think this answers the first question.

As for the second question, you should have an external event store.

These two patterns are well described in this [book](https://microservices.io/book).